# Trying to mimic the linux cat command using a producer consumer model but ouput seems to show multiple copies of a line

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, producer-consumer

Like in my title, my goal is to use the producer consumer model to mimic the linux cat command(ouput the contents of the file to screen). When I try running the program using lab3 5 animals.txt (lab3 the compiled/renamed executable, 5 being the size of the bounded buffer, and test_alarm.cpp being the name of the file to be printed), lines in the ouput seem to have been outputted multiple times. I am not sure what could be causing this(maybe I am not deleting the contents of the buffer properly? Though I'm not sure why that would cause multiple prints), so any help is appreciated.

An oddpoint is when I change the positions of 'ifstream infile' from global to the producer func, the output seems to change as well.

```
Animals.txt (output using linux's 'cat')
I have a dog
Dogs are large
I also have a cat
```

```
Animals.txt (output using my program)
I have a dog
Dogs are large
I also have a cat

I have a dog
Dogs are large
I also have a cat
I have a dog
Dogs are large
I have a dog
```

```
(Latest output)
counter in prod is: 1
counter in prod is: 2
counter in prod is: 3
I have a dog
counter in consumer is: 3
Dogs are large
counter in consumer is: 2

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int counter = 0; //number of words in buffer
int buffmax; //size of buffer
string filename;
mutex mu;
condition_variable cond;
string* buffer;
bool flag = false;
ifstream infile; 


void produce()
{
        
        infile.open(filename);

        while(getline(infile, temp)) //!infile.eof()
        {
                unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu);
                cond.wait(locker, []() {return counter < buffmax; }); //if true then produce, if false then wait
                buffer[counter] = temp;
                //infile >> buffer[counter];
                counter++;
                //cout << "counter in prod is: " << counter << endl;
                locker.unlock();
                cond.notify_one(); //notify consumer thread
        }
        infile.close();
        flag = true;
}


void consume()
{
        
        while(true)
        {
                if (flag == true && counter <= 0)
                        break;
        unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu);
                cond.wait(locker, []() {return counter > 0; });
           
                cout << buffer[0] << endl;
                string *x = new string[buffmax];
                for(int i = 0; i < counter-1; i++) // reason for seg fault?
                {
                   x[i]=buffer[i+1];
                }
                delete [] buffer;
                buffer = NULL
                buffer = x;
                x = NULL;
                //cout << "counter in consumer is: " << counter << endl;
                counter--;
                
                locker.unlock();
                cond.notify_one(); //notify producer thread
        }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string s = argv[1];
    buffmax = stoi(s); //size of the buffer
    filename = string(argv[2]); // name of file to be parsed
    buffer = new string[buffmax]; // creating the bounded buffer
    
    thread t1(produce);
    thread t2(consume);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Recommended reading: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: I'll take a look

Comment: Print out the value of counter when entering each function's critical section and again when exiting. You should see you're not reducing it enough when consuming.

Comment: I redid the loop by creating a global string temp and doing while(infile >> temp). I ran the program then and noticed the first word of each sentence got cut off. Ex: 'have a dog' . I am assuming this has something to do with the counter issue you mentioned. Will look into it.

Comment: `while(infile >> temp)` reads a single whitespace-delimited token (effectively the first word) into `temp`. If you never use `temp` for anything it is wasted. This also does not protect `getline(infile, buffer[counter]);` from undetected failure. What you want is something closer to `while (getline(infile, buffer[counter]))`, but since this would place modification of the buffer outside the protection of the mutex, bad smurf will ensue.

Comment: The easy hack is `while (getline(infile, temp)` and then inside the mutex lock `buffer[counter] = temp;`. You can speed this up a bit by reading directly into `buffer[counter]` if you bundle the critical section into a function and return a bool.

Comment: yes that was what I was confused by, how can I fix my while loop without taking my buffer outside the critical section?

Comment: will try thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Side note: `bool flag = false;` is used by both threads outside of synchronization. This is somehting you'll probably get away with, but if you don't it's a real mind<expletive deleted> to figure out what went wrong. consider replacing it with `std::atomic_flag`.

Comment: will do. currently working on the counter sync issue : producer prints 1, 2, 3, while consumer prints 2, 1, 0

Comment: I have updated my code and the latest ouput along with it. However, I seem to be getting a seg fault error. Not sure what I am not allowed to access in this case. The misaligned counters in prod and consumer can be ignored mostly since they depend on the cout position.

Comment: for any1 in the future the code is now fully working

Answer (score 2):

In `consume`

```
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        cout << buffer[i] << endl; //output contents of buffer
    counter--;
```

consumes `counter` buffers and only decreases `counter` by 1. This could be solved by reducing counter to zero, but that pretty much defeats the point of using the buffer in the first place.

A potential proper solution would be to replace the linear buffer with a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) or a [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)).

Comment: the assignment details the use of only static or dynamic arrays no use of vectors queues etc. Otherwise I personally would have used a vector.

Comment: Since this is a homework question I have to be careful how much I implement for you. `std::queue` wouldn't be the right tool for this job anyway because it grows. I think an unspoken part of the assignment is for you to write your own queue. Look around for papers and documentation on lock-free queues. Implement one correctly and it does almost all of your work for you.